# Shapes in emails - a good practice?

Tags: html, css, email, css-shapes

I'm sending emails to my clients with voucher info. I'd like to graphically represent a voucher.

I came up with an idea to style tables (as tables are well recieved in email clients)  - check code snippet for my solution.

I do not want to go for images, since they are disabled by default in most email clients.

> My question being: is it well recieved by mail clients and programs or should I refrain from such practice?

```css
 #badge-ribbon { 
   position: relative; 
   background: red; 
   height: 100px; width: 100px; 
   -moz-border-radius: 50px; 
   -webkit-border-radius: 50px; 
   border-radius: 50px; 
 } 
#badge-ribbon:before, #badge-ribbon:after { 
  content: ''; 
  position: absolute; 
  border-bottom: 70px solid red; 
  border-left: 40px solid transparent; 
  border-right: 40px solid transparent; 
  top: 70px; 
  left: -10px; 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-140deg); 
  -moz-transform: rotate(-140deg); 
  -ms-transform: rotate(-140deg); 
  -o-transform: rotate(-140deg); } 
#badge-ribbon:after { 
  left: auto; 
  right: -10px; 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(140deg); 
  -moz-transform: rotate(140deg); 
  -ms-transform: rotate(140deg); 
  -o-transform: rotate(140deg); 
}
```

```html
 <table id="badge-ribbon">
```

Comment: You could include an ascii-art version in the plain-text alternative :)

Comment: The problem sometimes is that it does not support in MS outlook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS in email is at about the CSS 1.8 level, it is rarely more exciting or usable than CSS in 1998 was. The best bet is to send a simple email with a HTML code overlay that uses `style` elements and `table` design structures. Images and large colour blocks are the best method as CSS 3 support is pretty non-existant and HTML CSS support in general is extremely patchy and uneven, depending even on how the CSS is presented, some things work as `style` elements but attaching CSS style sheets are usually severed from the HTML code.

CSS3 is generally not supported by email clients.

Have a simple clean email with bright bold colour block and/or images and a clear clean link to a webpage showing the same message in beautiful HTML5 and CSS3.

Answer (score 4):

I'd avoid using this technique and go with images as there's a good chance a lot of this CSS won't work in Outlook clients and Gmail will strip out embedded CSS completely. A fallback for images not loading is using the Alt tag to deliver a headline/copy

[Campaign Monitor CSS support guide](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)